# Walking the line. With Offtopic

Tags: discussion, scope

I just asked this question on SO.
[Securing android Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658850/securing-android-devices)
And I am not convinced that this is off Topic.

Like the Reason already says: **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.**

So my Question is would you consider a Tool/Workflow for Signing your Binarys are part of your Development Environment or not?

I would asume that it is. Couse it will be part of your build chain like adding Metainformations. **Thats just my conclusion, what are you thinking about this?
 :D**

Comment: If we agreed that it was On Topic (which I don't, nor do I think it's a close call or "on the line") it would still be far Too Broad, and closed for that reason.

Comment: It is not a programming question.  A programmer might know something about it, but he also knows what kind of coffee tastes good.  It is a coffee question.  You can post this to the android.se site.

Comment: @HansPassant:  I wouldn't even want it on Android.SE.  It's too disjoint and too all-around to be answerable concisely.  But I suppose it's really up to them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The phrase

> My Phone just died

almost ***immediately*** quantifies this as a question aimed at power users or consumers of Android phones, and ***not*** Android developers.

If we follow this up with the rest of your question:

> During this I asked my self what are the security features that modern Smartphones have? (Especially Android Phones)

Well...that's still not a programming question.  That's a security question about phones *in general*.

There's nothing here that a developer would be able to contribute to this discussion, since your average developer may not fully understand these things.  Additionally, there's nothing here that immediately strikes me as being an actual programming problem or exercise; you're just out in the market and happen to be curious about phones.

This question is wholly off-topic.